# android bulid support not working with Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

[image]i want to run my unity project in my phone but when try to build the project it showing no android modules added , But i installed you can see on the image

[image]
[image]

Comment: Follow this link https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive , select your unity version, click on `Release notes`, Go to `Additional download` section, you can get the `Android target support` from there. Based on your screen shot just click on this link https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2020.3.5 , for `2020.3.5f1` version

Comment: i downloaded now android is showing, but i got warnings that JDK, SDK, NDK is missing download it from unity Hub. Image attached

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the versions of Unity you are using and the one you installed the modules in. From my experience in using unity, each update creates a separate unity version, thus the version you are using might be different than the version 2020.3.5f1 that you installed the modules in.

Answer (score 0):

Download Unity Hub version of Unity installer. Then you will be able to set modules for Unity version you downloaded from Unity Hub. Don`t forget add scene and press button Add Open Scenes )